# JPA/EclipseLink mixing batch fetch strategies on different collections

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a JPA / JPQL query in EclipseLink 2.3.2 and I'm providing a batch-fetch query hint on multiple collections

```
hints={
  @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH, value="obj.collection1"),
  @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH, value="obj.group.members"),
  @QueryHint(name=QueryHints.BATCH_TYPE, value="IN"),
}
```

Is there a way to specify different batch fetch types on different collections, such that I can get `obj.collection1` with `JOIN` and `obj.group.members` with `IN` or `EXISTS`?

Or do they all have to be the same?

The practical application is that with a fetch on nested collections, there may be different cardinalities at different levels.  For example, for the initial query, there might be thousands of rows returned so I couldn't use "IN" for `obj.collection1` without possibly breaking Oracle syntax limits on the IN clause.  On the other hand, for `obj.group.members` there might only be a few distinct values of `group` so an IN clause would make more sense.

Comment: Have you had any success with this? Thanks.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Over eight years has passed and this is still relevant...